# PowerShell to open gzip stream

Tags: powershell

Web searches for `$s=New-Object IO.MemoryStream(,[Convert]::FromBase64String())` show numerous Pastebin's for similar events, but I cannot figure out how to decode it myself.  The original base64 I decode with

```
param( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
[string]$b64
)
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("$b64"))
```

which gives me this:

```
$s=New-Object IO.MemoryStream(,[Convert]::FromBase64String("Encrypted-String"))
IEX (New-Object IO.StreamReader(New-Object IO.Compression.GzipStream($s,[IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress))).ReadToEnd();
```

I have been unable to figure out how to use PowerShell to decompress the "Encrypted-String" so I can analyze what's happening.

I've seen similar posts but nothing answers my question of how to decode it myself.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to decompress a gzip comressed string with PowerShell? gzip is only mentioned in the title, while you are saying base64 in the question's body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize for the formatting, I am still learning the nuances of posting questions/anwers on here.  I also apologize if my question wasn't clear, but after much luck with today's research (been trying to figure this out for the past year).

I found a link (https://blog.kenaro.com/2010/10/19/how-to-embedd-compressed-scripts-in-other-powershell-scripts/) which gave me enough information to build this script.  Thank you Ingo Karstein for your blog and all who viewed and asked for clarification.

The gzip stream is part of the results that needed further analysis which I was unable to figure out.

I create a folder in my Temp with the name of the machine that I obtained the suspicious batch file from that calls the encoded powershell command; remove all but the base64 code and rename it to a .txt file.  I then run the code below with the computername and the file name to see what the attacker was doing.  The answer that works for me:

```
( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
[string]$HostIP,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
[string]$file
)

New-Item C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results -ItemType Directory

$b64 = Get-Content C:\Temp\$HostIP\$file.txt -Raw
Write-Host
$results = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("$b64")) 
$results | Out-File C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\unicode_$file.txt

$ec64 = Get-Content C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\unicode_$file.txt
$eb64 = $ec64|%{$_.split('"')[1]}

$data = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String("$eb64")
$ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStream
$ms.Write($data, 0, $data.Length)
$ms.Seek(0,0) | Out-Null

$cs = New-Object IO.Compression.GZipStream($ms, [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
$sr = New-Object IO.StreamReader($cs)
$t = $sr.readtoend()
$t | Out-File C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\decompressed_$file.txt

$dcb64 = Get-Content C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\decompressed_$file.txt
$dc64 = $dcb64|%{$_.split('"')[1]}

$utf = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("$dc64"))
$utf | Out-File C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\utf8_$file.txt

$asc = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("$dc64"))
$asc | Out-File C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\ascii_$file.txt

$utf8 = "C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\utf8_$file.txt"
$ascii = "C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\ascii_$file.txt"

(Get-Content "$utf8") -replace "`0", "" | Set-Content "C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\utf8_no-null_$file.txt"
(Get-Content "$ascii") -replace "`0", "" | Set-Content "C:\Temp\$HostIP\Results\ascii_no-null_$file.txt"
```

'